# Convertir objeto javascript de un tipo concreto a genérico

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

He creado una clase Persona, necesito usarla para crear un objeto de tipo genérico.

```
class Person
{
  constructor(name, age)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.age  = age;
  }

  get()
  {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Es decir, un objeto del tipo contenido el siguiente array:

```
const people = [
  {
    name: 'Foo',
    age: 23
  },
  {
    name: 'Baz',
    age: 63
  },
];
```

Ahora, creo una persona y la añado al array anterior:

```
const person1 = new Person('John', 18);
const newPeople = [...people, person1];
```

Al mostrar por consola:

```
console.log(newPeople);
```

Obtengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o en texto (resumiendo):

```
0: {name: "Foo", age: 23}
1: {name: "Baz", age: 63}
2: Person {name: "John", age: 18}
```

Cuando lo que necesito sería:

```
0: {name: "Foo", age: 23}
1: {name: "Baz", age: 63}
2: {name: "John", age: 18}
```

> **Nota:** el método `get()` de `Persona` lo he puesto para probar diferentes
>   salidas, aunque no encontré la solución...

Comment: Se me ocurren varias formas. Utilizar ```JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(person1))``` o tener un método en la clase que devuelva un objeto con las propiedades `return { ...this }`

Comment: Puedes intentar la idea de Jose, o declarar tu objeto como let person= {
 name: "Malcolm",
      age:  18
};. En tu objeto get estas devolviendo todo el objeto. prodrias devolver solo las propiedades. {name...}

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo si lo devuelvo desestructurado con el  `return { ...this }` en el método `get()` va perfecto, gracias. No se me había ocurrido.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo, considera crear una respuesta con las soluciones comentadas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la [sintaxis de spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Sintaxis_Spread):

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  
  get jsonObject() {
    return { ...this };
  }
}

const jose = new Person('Jose', 'Joven');

console.log(jose.jsonObject);
```

Como vemos, solo nos muestra propiedades enumerables:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  
  get jsonObject() {
    return { ...this };
  }
}

const jose = new Person('Jose', 'Joven');

Object.defineProperty(jose, 'isBeatiful', {
  enumerable: false,
  value: true // Soy guapo, pero ella no lo sabe :(
});

console.log(jose.jsonObject);
```

Sería equivalente a usar [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/assign) de la siguiente forma:

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
  
  get jsonObject() {
    return Object.assign({}, this);
  }
}

const jose = new Person('Jose', 'Joven');

console.log(jose.jsonObject);
```